# system with parameter

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

$$\left\{\begin{matrix}
2(x+y)&+ \ mxy  &=5 \\ 
(m-1)(x+y) &+ \ xy  &=1 \\ 
3(x+y) &-\ xy  &=m+1 
\end{matrix}\right.$$

I need to find the number of $m$ values such that this system has solutions $(x,y)\in \mathbb R \times \mathbb R$.

After I noted $x+y=s$ and $xy=p$ I obtained a system in $s$ and $p$.From the last 2 equations I get $s=1$ and $p=2-m$ then I replace these values in first equation and I get $p=3/m$.Then I get $3/m=2-m$ with no real solutions.

Where's my mistake?There's another method to approach this system ?The right answer is $1$.

Comment: Your mistake is in *From the last 2 equations I get s=1.* It should be *From the last 2 equations I get $(m+2)s=m+2.$* You continued with $s=1$ which doesn't lead to a solution. You have to check also the possibility $m=-2.$

Comment: thank you, I got it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summing of the second and the third equations gives:
$$(m+2)(x+y)=m+2.$$
1. $m=-2$.

We have, $$2(x+y)-2xy=5$$ and $$3(x+y)-xy=-1,$$ which gives
$$xy=-\frac{17}{4}<0,$$ which says that our system has solutions.

2. $m\neq-2$.

Thus, $$x+y=1,$$
$$xy=\frac{3}{m}$$ and $$xy=2-m,$$ which gives
$$\frac{3}{m}=2-m$$ or
$$m^2-2m+3=0,$$ which is impossible.

Id est, there is unique value of $m$, for which our system has solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Eliminating $$xy$$ so we get for $$x+y$$ two equations
$$(x+y)(2-m^2+m)=5-m$$ and
$$(x+y)(m+2)=m+2$$
Can you proceed?

Comment: I got the same thing. x+y=1 how to continue ?

Comment: $$x+y=1$$ only if $$m+2\neq 0$$, then you get $$2-m^2+m=5-m$$

Comment: Equation which has no real solutions.